# class ActivityResultCallback : Java.Lang.Object, IActivityResultCallback result is always null

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I have converted my old `StartActivityForResult` code to the new `RegisterForActivityResult` as `StartActivityForResult` is depreciated in the android API 29 and higher.  My new code works perfectly, except that `result` in `class ActivityResultCallback` is always null.  I need to be able to know when the user cancels the taking of the picture when they hit the back button, otherwise the app crashes (if a previous picture doesn't already exist) or a previously taken picture is processed again.  My code (showing only the relevant code):

```
public class Photo : AppCompatActivity
{
    public ImageView MyImageView;
    public ImageButton camerabutton;
    public bool PictureTaken = false;
    private CurrentSubjectInfo MySubjectInfo;
    private ActivityResultCallback _activityResultCallback;
    private ActivityResultLauncher _activityResultLauncher;
    private Uri uri;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        try 
        {
            _activityResultCallback = new ActivityResultCallback();
            _activityResultCallback.OnActivityResultCalled += ActivityResultCallback_ActivityResultCalled;
            _activityResultLauncher = RegisterForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(), _activityResultCallback);
            RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Photo);
            PictureTaken = false;
            MySubjectInfo = new CurrentSubjectInfo("", "", "", "", "");
            // retrieve subject information from previous activity
            MySubjectInfo = Mybundle.GetParcelable("MySubjectInfo", Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(CurrentSubjectInfo))) as CurrentSubjectInfo;
            ImageButton camerabutton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.button1);
            MyImageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

            camerabutton.Click += (sender, evt) =>
            {

                var cameraispresent = CheckCameraHardware();
                if (cameraispresent)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // get directory where pictures are stored
                        App._dir = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures);
                        // build file name
                        MySubjectInfo.Name = MySubjectInfo.Name.Replace(",", "");
                        MySubjectInfo.Name = MySubjectInfo.Name.Replace(" ", "");
                        MySubjectInfo.Name = MySubjectInfo.Name.Replace(".", "");
                        var filename = MySubjectInfo.Name + ".jpg";
                        App._file = new File(App._dir, String.Format(filename, Guid.NewGuid()));
                        uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, this.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider",App._file);
                        // launch camera activity
                        _activityResultLauncher.Launch(uri);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // trap error and log it
                    };

                }
            };
        }
    }
    Boolean CheckCameraHardware()
    {
        Android.Content.PM.PackageManager pm = PackageManager;
        if (pm.HasSystemFeature(Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureCamera))
        {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void ActivityResultCallback_ActivityResultCalled(object sender, ActivityResult result)
    {
        // result is always null, so I don't check it
        try
        {
            // Because the resulting bitmap is rotated and too large, I set original orientation and resize
            // suffice it to say it works perfectly so I won't post the code here
            int height = 260;
            int width = 200;
            App.bitmap = App._file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(width, height);

            Bitmap bitmap = App.bitmap;
            var filePath = App._file.AbsolutePath;
            // save the resized bitmap, overwriting original file
            var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
            stream.Close();
            // set the imageview to the resulting bitmap
            MyImageView.SetImageBitmap (App.bitmap);
            // cleanup
            bitmap = null;
            App.bitmap = null;
            PictureTaken = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PictureTaken = false;
            // trap and log error
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `ActivityResultCallback` class:

```
public class ActivityResultCallback : Java.Lang.Object, IActivityResultCallback
{
    public EventHandler<ActivityResult> OnActivityResultCalled;

    public void OnActivityResult(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        ActivityResult activityResult = result as ActivityResult;
        OnActivityResultCalled?.Invoke(this, activityResult);
    }
}
```

As stated all this code executes perfectly with no errors except that `Java.Lang.Object result` is always null.  I need to know when the user cancels the camera activity, I would assume that `Java.Lang.Object result` would indicate `cancelled` but I get nothing.  What am I missing?

Comment: `_activityResultCallback.OnActivityResultCalled += ActivityResultCallback_ActivityResultCalled;` ?????

Comment: Is there a question?  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some playing around I noticed that the parameter `Java.Lang.Object result` in the `ActivityResultCallback` class was either `true` or `false` depending on what the user did with the camera.  So I changed the class to:

```
public class ActivityResultCallback : Java.Lang.Object, IActivityResultCallback
{
    public EventHandler<ActivityResult> OnActivityResultCalled;
    
    public void OnActivityResult(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {

        ActivityResult activityResult;
        if ((bool)result)
        {
            activityResult = new ActivityResult((int)Result.Ok, null);
        } else
        {
            activityResult = new ActivityResult((int)Result.Canceled, null);
        }
        OnActivityResultCalled?.Invoke(this, activityResult);
    }
}
```

In the `ActivityResultCallback_ActivityResultCalled` function, I modified it to this:

```
    private void ActivityResultCallback_ActivityResultCalled(object sender, ActivityResult result)
    {

        try
        {
            if (result.ResultCode == (int)Result.Ok)
            {
                int height = 260;
                int width = 200;
                App.bitmap = App._file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(width, height);

                Bitmap bitmap = App.bitmap;
                var filePath = App._file.AbsolutePath;
                var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
                bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
                stream.Close();

                MyImageView.SetImageBitmap(App.bitmap);

                bitmap = null;
                App.bitmap = null;
                PictureTaken = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // trap and log error
        }
    }
```

`activityResult` apparently has, at a minimum, two parameters, the result and data.  I already had what I needed for data so I set that to null and cast `Result.Ok` or `Result.Cancelled` to int depending on whether result was true or false.  I still don't totally understand how to use the new `ActivityForResult` API, but this works for me and I'm running with it.